# Particles are in front of UI elements in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

So all i'm looking for is simple. I want the UI elements such as Buttons/Logo/..etc to be in front any particle effects in the Canvas.

[image]

In the answer [Here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1152887/how-to-place-a-particle-between-2-ui-objects.html) someone suggested to add a canvas component to each and every UI element I want to show in front of the particles and that work somehow the only problem in this way the **buttons won't click at all.**

All elements are on the default sorting layer including the particles object and the camera.

Is that hard to do that?

Please help.

Comment: When you add a canvas, you also need to add a Graphic Raycaster for the input to be working under those canvases.

Answer (score 1):

set "Order in layer" of Particles to 0 and UI elements to 1 or a better way of doing this is to go to add new layers, create a foreground and background layer, set foreground to 1 and background to 0 and then change from the default layer to which ever you want in front or back.

Comment: You cant change sorting layer for each ui element in the canvas

Comment: bro are you evening looking properly? I can see sorting layer in inspector.

Comment: look beneath cast shadow

Comment: this was very helpful thanks. been pulling my hair for days on this

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to change the material I was using in the particle system. Change "Sprite-Default" to a material with "Rendering Mode" Opaque and "Shader" to "Standard".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).